# Android navigation component with popupTo and popUpToInclusive onResume not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, fragment-backstack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to figure out how the navigation component works. Here's my fragments, SignIn Fragment and HomeFragment. In my navigation graph I have the following

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/signInFragment"
        android:name="com.nitsua.chatapp.screen.authentication.SignInFragment"
        android:label="SignInFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_signin">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigate_to_home"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/signInFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.nitsua.chatapp.screen.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"/>
```

If I understand is correct, when I use the action: navigate_to_home, it will clear the fragment backstack until signInFragment including it because of popUpToInclusive set to true. If it is not set to true. SignInFragment will not be removed in backstack.

I tried signInFragment -> homeFragment, then homeFragment and back button. It works fine. It doesn't go to sign in and the app goes out of foreground. Then I try to open again the app from background. I **expect** the app to be in **HomeFragment** but it is in SignInFragment. The fragment backstack should store the HomeFragment transaction, is that right? then when it resume, it should resume the HomeFragment. but why it resumed the SignInFragment? Am I missing something? Can someone explain to me and recommend a way to resume to HomeFragment instead on SignInFragment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the signInFragment as an Activity. Check in your MainActivity if you have to show the signInActivity. If yes then start the activity.

Or you could start your homeFragment and right after that start the signInFragment if log in is required.

Then use this in your signInFragment.

```
navController.popBackStack(R.id.homeFragment, false)
```

Will pop your backstack till it reaches the first instance of homeFragment.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. I found my mistake. I thought that the back button doesn't destroy the activity but it is. That's why the fragments and activity are created from start. I should add logic to save the credentials and save it somewhere then navigate to home fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into problem when start using navigation component but unfortunately Navigation component not provide any solution yet to call onResume when backStack or popup to another fragment .It reCreate the backfragment again when press back button.
My solution:

My data is in repository (Either getting from local Db or remote ).
Then create a LiveData in ViewModel and change his value false to true when first time load data from Api or Database .After then when user press back button check from liveData if value is true then get data from viewmodel and not calling the api.

private val localOrRemoteData=MutableLiveData()

```
fun setLocalOrRemoteData(status:Boolean){
    localOrRemoteData.value=status
}


fun getLocalOrRemoteData():MutableLiveData<Boolean>{
    return localOrRemoteData
}



getLocalOrRemoteData().observeOnce(lifecycleOwner) {
        temp = it
    }
```